# If $A^2=I$, why $1$ is not necessarily an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathcal M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ s.t. $A^2=I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix on $\mathcal M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$). Why I thought is that $(A-I)(A+I)=0$ and thus $p(x)=(x-1)(x+1)$ is the characteristic polynomial, and thus $1$ and $-1$ are eigenvalue. But if I take $A=-I$, then $A^2=I$, but the only eigen value is $-1$. Any explanation on that ? What am I mistaken ?

Comment: Why should $p$ be the characteristic polynomial ? There can exists several polynomials of the same degree, that vanish at $A$.

Comment: What's wrong in $A^2-I=(A-I)(A+I)$ ? @TheSilverDoe

Comment: I mean that the fact that $p(A)=0$ does not imply that $p$ is the characteristic polynomial ! Even if it has the good degree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$p(A)=0$ does not imply, even if $\deg A$ is equal to the size of the matrix, that $p$ is a scalar multiple of the characteristic polynomial. It only means that all the irreducible factors of the characteristic polynomial divide $p$, but they need not have the same multiplicity. In your case, for instance, it is entirely possible that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $T+1$, and then the characteristic polynomial would be $(T+1)^2$.

Comment: I found the middle part of your answer confusing, even though I think it is worded correctly - I believe you are asserting that every irreducible factor of char. poly. divides $p$, and also that not every irreducible factor of $p$ must be an irreducible factor of the char. poly. ? This might be obvious, but I at least had to say it to myself out loud to understand your last statement.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I don't know what may make it confusing, but note that the subject of "divide" can only be "all the irreducible factors". @preferred_anon

Answer (score 2):

From $A^2=I$ you can only conclude that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda^2=1$. This is what you can observe in your examples. For instance, taking $A=-I$, $A^2 = I$ and the only eigenvalue is $-1$.